# Noun + し (日本語を勉強し始めたきっかけ)

Tags: grammar, compound-verbs

What is the function of し here?

> 日本語を勉強し始めたきっかけ、そして日本語学習の目標は何ですか

How does it differ from

> 日本語を勉強始めたきっかけ、そして日本語学習の目標は何ですか

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This し is the masu-stem (or continuative-form) of する. `masu-stem + 始める` means "to start V-ing". For example, 食べ始める means "to start eating", 見始める means "to start watching", and 運転し始める means "to start driving".

日本語を勉強始めたきっかけ is simply ungrammatical because 勉強 is not marked with a particle, and を cannot be an omitted particle because を is already used before 勉強 (日本語を勉強をする is wrong).

- [Difference Between べんきょう する and べんきょうを する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5010)
- [Jlpt/n5q5: 弟は部屋◯掃除をしました。◯: の versus に option](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26120/5010)
- [の or を？ What is the correct answer and why is it correct?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44972/5010)

So here's the summary:

|  | without 始める | with 始める |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 勉強 as a suru-verb | 日本語を勉強する to study Japanese | 日本語を勉強し始める to start studying Japanese |
| 勉強 as a noun | 日本語の勉強をする to do study of Japanese | 日本語の勉強を始める to start study of Japanese |